# Why do Force Ghosts wear the clothes we see them in?

Tags: star-wars, force-ghost

Are there any sources that explain why force ghosts wear those particular clothes? And why Obi Wan is seen needing to hold up his robes?

Comment: You don’t want to see naked force ghosts running around, do you?

Comment: The bigger question would be: Why would you want to see them naked? And who are you interested to see naked? Obi-Wan? Old Anakin? Young Anakin?...Yoda?

Comment: Force ghosts presumably don’t need clothes to keep warm, but you still don’t want everyone to see [how big your Schwartz is](https://youtu.be/pPkWZdluoUg?t=43s).

Comment: In-universe, perhaps the ghosts want to appear in a form that is easily recognizable.

Comment: Probably for a similar reason we don't bury corpses naked...

Comment: Why ought they not to wear clothes?

Comment: Other ghosts, like in our own galaxy, aren't naked either, so why should they?

Comment: It would certainly bring a new terror to the line "Annie? Little Annie??"

Comment: Casper is the only nekkid ghost I'm aware of.

Comment: There are already Star Wars movies with no clothes, like "Amidala, Queen of Naboob", "Sith On My Face" and "The Adventures of Jango Phatt; Intergalactic Booty Hunter"

Comment: @Mozart Where is Obi-Wan seen holding up his robes? Is there a particular scene you're referring to?

Comment: Apologies if the edit has gone to far.  Feel free to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've not asked for an in-universe reason, I'll go with the out-of-universe reason. **Because it's a film that is intended to be suitable for children.**

While it's perfectly possible to include [full-frontal male nudity](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/61298840.jpg) in a film without attracting [the wrath of the MPAA](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QzaLu7-YETEC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=rating%20non-sexual%20male%20nudity&source=bl&ots=NslLvNpmmn&sig=D7yRRdMCTKa5tLw7cDQQMGWEWzk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rating%20non-sexual%20male%20nudity&f=false), the reality is that an extended shot of Obi-Wan walking around naked would have almost certainly earned the film an NC-17 rating, resulting in its box-office take being slashed by approximately 90%.

It's also pretty unlikely that an actor of Sir Alec's fame would agree to take part in a film that required gratuitous and unnecessary frontal nudity, given [his reluctance](http://dangerousminds.net/comments/alec_guinness_a.k.a._obi_wan_kenobi_kind_of_hated_star_wars) to star in the film in the first place.

Comment: Same principle, in other words: we make the excuse that Force ghosts can't be naked so that the actors involved will be willing to act the scenes out, just like how we make the excuse that there's no underwear in space so that the actresses involved will be willing to act the scenes out. #StarWarsLogic

Comment: @thegreatjedi - I've made a detailed study of Carrie Fisher's outfits and I have concluded that with the exception of her white flowing robes (where her breasts were taped up) and her Slave bikini (which famously was quite revealing from above), she was almost certainly wearing underwear in every single scene. Padmé seems to have followed the same principle. There might be no underwear in space, but that doesn't mean that there's no boob-tape.

Comment: Sorry I know that is pg, but I meant any in universe reason.